# How can I stop Atom adding a space when I start a new line?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using a text editor called [Atom](https://atom.io/). When I start a new line by pressing enter, the editor automatically adds a space; which I don't need. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Figuring out the cause

To know what's triggered when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, you can enable the **Key Binding Resolver** through the command palette or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (dot key):

[image: Key binding resolver in the command palette]

It should bring a new pane at the bottom of the editor which shows the last input from the keyboard and lists all the triggered actions in order.

[image: Key binding resolver resolving enter as an example]

From there, you can pinpoint the plugin which may do what you don't want.

## Fix the problem

- disable the culprit plugin
- disable this plugin keybindings and implement your own inside your personal `keymap.cson` file.

  Here's a part of my `keymap.cson` which swaps docblockr commands.

  ```cson
  'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
    # docblockr keybindings
    'tab': 'docblockr:parse-tab'
    'enter': 'docblockr:parse-inline'
    'shift-enter': 'docblockr:parse-enter'
  ```
- sometimes, after a plugin update, rebooting Atom or just reloading the window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> fixes keybinding problems.